# Probability that a number is a generator of a subgroup of $Z_p^*$ of order $q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a random, large prime, what is the probability that a random element $x$ in $Z_p$ is a generator of a subgroup of $Z_p^*$ of order $q$, where $q$ is the largest number in the prime factorization of $p-1$?

Comment: By "the largest number in the prime factorization", you mean the largest prime or the largest prime power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any cyclic group of order $n$, for every divisor $d\mid n$ there are exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$. In your case, the probability would then be
$$\frac{\varphi(q)}{p-1}$$
because $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic. (Note that there is *exactly one* subgroup of order $q$.)

Comment: I'm looking to generate a pretty large group, where $2$ is generating a specific subgroup in it. Is there any particular theorem for an even base or something to predict the probability of $2$ to generate such a subgroup by generating groups over and over? Or does the probability that 2 is generating my subgroup of order $p-1$ is the same as $\frac{\varphi(q)}{p-1}$?

Comment: Also since q is prime, the above part of the fraction is just $q$. Rewriting it as $\frac{q}{\varphi(p)}$ would be clearer.